# How to read file as .dat and write it as a .txt

Tags: python-3.x, pickle

So I'm making a thing where it reads data from a .dat file and saves it as a list, then it takes that list and writes it to a .txt file (basically a .dat to .txt converter). However, whenever I run it and it makes the file, it is a .txt file but it contains the .dat data. After troubleshooting the variable that is written to the .dat file is normal legible .txt not weird .dat data...

Here is my code (pls don't roast I'm very new I know it sucks and has lots of mistakes just leave me be xD):

```
#import dependencies
import sys
import pickle
import time

#define constants and get file path
data = []
index = 0
path = input("Absolute file path:\n")

#checks if last character is a space (common in copy+pasting) and removes it if there is a space
if path.endswith(' '):
    path = path[:-1]


#load the .dat file into a list names bits
bits = pickle.load(open(path, "rb"))

with open(path, 'rb') as fp:
    bits = pickle.load(fp)

#convert the data from bits into a new list called data
while index < len(bits):
    print("Decoding....\n")
    storage = bits[index]
    print("Decoding....\n")
    str(storage)
    print("Decoding....\n")
    data.append(storage)
    print("Decoding....\n")
    index += 1
    print("Decoding....\n")
    time.sleep(0.1)

#removes the .dat of the file
split = path[:-4]

#creates the new txt file with _converted.txt added to the end
with open(f"{split}_convert.txt", "wb") as fp:
    pickle.dump(data, fp)

#tells the user where the file has been created
close_file = str(split)+"_convert.txt"
print(f"\nA decoded txt file has been created. Run this command to open it: cd {close_file}\n\n")
```

Quick review; I'm setting a variable named data which contains all of the data from the .dat file, then I want to the save the variable to a .txt file, but whenever I save it to a .txt file it has the contents of the .dat file, even though when I call print(data) it tells me the data in normal, legible text. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
with open(f"{split}_convert.txt", "wb") as fp:
    pickle.dump(data, fp)
```

When you're opening the file in `wb` mode, it will automatically write binary data to it. To write plain text to .txt file, use

```
with open(f"{split}_convert.txt", "w") as fp:
    fp.write(data)
```

Since `data` is a list, you can't write it straight away as well. You'll need to write each item, using a loop.

```
with open(f"{split}_convert.txt", "w") as fp:
    for line in data:
        fp.write(line)
```

For more details on file writing, check this article as well: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python3/python_files_io.htm

Comment: I have tried that, every time I do it the file ends up blank.

Comment: Yes, that works but I would prefer to get a .txt file.

Comment: Thank you so much!